# iPhone sdk, ignore code in simulator?

Tags: iphone

Im sure this is simple, but I have been googling for an hour and cannot find anything.

Basically I have a block of code that I want ignored on the simulator, but to run on the iphone.

```
self.musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
// assign a playback queue containing all media items on the device
[myPlayer setQueueWithQuery: [MPMediaQuery songsQuery]];

// start playing from the beginning of the queue
[myPlayer play];
```

I tried adding:

```
#if !SIMULATOR
#endif
```

around the code, but that did not work. Im sure there must be something simple that I am just not finding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#if defined(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.

Comment: TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR is always defined on iOS, you need to check with `#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this annotation to wrap the code you want to ignore in the simulator:

```
#if !targetEnvironment(simulator)
...
#endif
```